# I have a problem with python while loop that executes one line of code twice

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a graph theory problem using breadth first traversal algorithm where the graph is represented as a grid.
The problem itself is from a local programming competition, so I can't share much details.

The input is provided for me (again, can't share it) in form of txt with some numerical values on each line that represent a grid size, position of start and finish points on that grid. Additionally, there are position of dangerous ares that I need to avoid.
I have no problem parsing the input. After that follows the code below. Some of the variables below are tuples because of the specific input and I thought that tuples could be good represention of x,y coordinate on a grid.

This is my code:

```py
from collections import deque

GRID = 3 #size of the grid
START = (1, 1) #start position
END = (0, 0) #finish position
SAFE = False #boolean, tells if I could delete one item from noareas
noareas = [ (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1) ] #position of dangerous areas I have to avoid


def gridmover(grid, x, y, stop_areas):
    dx = [-1, +1, 0, 0]
    dy = [0, 0, +1, -1]
    neighbours = []

    for i in range(4):
        xx = x + dx[i]
        yy = y + dy[i]
        if xx < 0 or yy < 0: continue
        if xx >= grid or yy >= grid: continue
        if (xx, yy) in stop_areas: continue
        neighbours.append((xx,yy))

    return neighbours

def breadthfirstsearch_custom(graph, start, end, stopareas, safe):
    queue = deque([ start ])
    visited = { start }
    i = 0

    while queue:
        current = queue.popleft() #this line executes twice
        path = [ current ]
        i += 1
        print(f"{i} This is current {current} and its type: {type(current)}")

        if current == end:
            return path

        if safe is True: stopareas.pop(0)
        neighbours = gridmover(graph, current[0], current[1], stopareas)

        for neighbour in neighbours:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                queue.extend(neighbour)
                path.extend(neighbour)
                visited.add(neighbour)

    return path

print(breadthfirstsearch_custom(GRID, START, END, noareas, SAFE))
```

Expected output should be a list of tuples that represent a path from start to finish.

This I see as an output:

```
1 This is current (1, 1) and its type: <class 'tuple'>
2 This is current 1 and its type: <class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home/repos/kisaievla_github/fiks9/kolo1/t1_plaz/playgrid.py", line 52, in <module>
    print(breadthfirstsearch_custom(GRID, START, END, noareas, PRKNO))
  File "/Users/home/repos/kisaievla_github/fiks9/kolo1/t1_plaz/playgrid.py", line 42, in breadthfirstsearch_custom
    neighbours = gridmover(graph, current[0], current[1], stopareas)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I understand the output above as while loop runs `current = queue.popleft()` twice. It pops a tuple from queue (desired behaviour) and then it pops an int from that tuple (not desired behaviour).

I send some time trying to find the issue. Hence the print statement in my code.
Strange thing is that when I have different values for `START` it behaves differently.
For example using the same code but with different variables

```py
START = (0, 0)
END = (0, 0)
```

Gives this:

```
1 This is current (0, 0) and its type: <class 'tuple'>
[(0, 0)]
```

which is really what I want, since start is the same as end and the path to it is the coordinates.

I really don't know or see the solution here. Maybe it's not even an issue with the loop itself, but with popping.
Thanks for the answer/comments in advance.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Your code is not working, you should clean it up and update your question. I didn't even check your problem with `current = queue.popleft()`. But know this: Popleft returns an element of array and you are trying to index this element, thats the reason for your TypeError Message. It is an int not a list. I would suggest you clean up your code, create variables with clear names instead of tupples with two values use single variables that explain the values. I think this would help you to get your code running.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question? Check out [ask] for tips, like how to write a good title. Please [edit] to clarify. I'm a graph theory noob myself, but if you showed the desired output, I might be able to help. My best guess is that `queue.extend` is supposed to be `queue.append`. I tried that for myself and the code finished at least, but I don't know if the answer is correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
        for neighbour in neighbours:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                queue.extend(neighbour)
                path.extend(neighbour)
                visited.add(neighbour)
```

`neighbours` is a list of tuples, returned from `gridmover`.  Thus, `neighbour` will be a tuple.

When you do `list.extend(tuple)`, that doesn't add the tuple to the list.  Instead, it extends the list with the individual members of the tuple.  If you do:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
lst.extend((4,5,6))
```

Then lst ends up as [1,2,3,4,5,6], NOT [1,2,3,(4,5,6)].

The simple answer is that you want append, not extend:

```
            queue.append(neighbour)
            path.append(neighbour)
```